# AJAX call is empty if response is too large

Tags: json, ajax, post

I have an AJAX call with POST data request. The URL file response is correct if I limit the query to 620 results, but with more results, the AJAX call returns an empty response, even with 200 code.
The response is in JSON.

My (partial) code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: {
            parameter1: parameter
        },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
```

Why ?

Comment: Old question but I'm currently experiencing the same. Except my database tables are pretty large so I can only return 3-4 rows at maximum, depending on what rows I try to get and how much data is in them. The only solution I can think of is to split the JSON data into multiple parts and deliver an [x] amount at a time.

Comment: Hi, do you have a solution for that? i face the same Problem when my response has more then 530.000 Entrys in the Array -> It is a JSON Array.